# Windows taskbar icon event type - WxPython Phoenix

Tags: events, wxpython, python-3.4

I am trying to find the event type associated with windows taskbar icon of my application. In Windows 8.1 user can close, minimize and restore the application from this icon.

[image: taskbar sample icons]

Google is only showing the results for taskbar *tray* icons, which is a whole different thing. So far I've tried these:

```
wx.EVT_CLOSE    # This event is not generated for taskbar closing
wx.EVT_RESTORE  # This event is not generated either
```

Yet, it does close the application and it also manages to restore an iconized application. I made two separate handlers to check this. They are working when I use the titlebar buttons (close and min/maximize buttons), but not when done from the taskbar.

Comment: Have you tried `wx.EVT_ICONIZE` ?

Comment: Yes, but it works only once (one minimize and then restore). After I restore my app, any further clicks on the taskbar icon does not create a wx.EVT_ICONIZE event. In Windows almost all programs can toggle between minimizing and restoring if the user keep pressing the taskbar icon.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using Windows since 3.0, but I haven't gotten 8.1 as of yet so I'm not sure what it's doing differently

Comment: @RenaeLider, I am on Windows 8.1 and just checked with my own shareware and clicking on its taskbar icon toggles between iconized and restored size, this is with either wxPython 2.9.5 on Py2.7 or a recent Phoenix build with Py3.4.  I am not aware of doing anything special.  Can you provide a sample app?

Comment: @Werner I tried a small app and it worked. Perhaps I am doing something wrong in my other script.Will it make a difference if it is a borderless frame? Mine has no window decorations around it. I am using `wx.NO_BORDER`